# Keep the content inside absolutely positioned DIVs centered (inside parent container)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a container with with fixed width and centered. Inside of the container I have two DIVs position relative to the window side by side. Inside of these Divs I've other content which I want to be centered (preferably with container).

here is simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/jTpGs/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<style>
 #container {
 width: 960px;
 height: 1000px;
 background: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }  

#windowdiv {
height: 200px;
background: purple;
padding-top: 20px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 30%;
top: 25px;
}
#windowdiv2 {
height: 200px;
background: blue;
padding-top: 20px;
position: absolute;
left: 60%;
right: 0;
top: 10px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'>

     <div id='windowdiv'>
        <p>some content</p>
     </div>
     <div id='windowdiv2'>
       <p>some content</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I find it a little unclear as to what it is you're asking for. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Check the code http://jsfiddle.net/jTpGs/. I want p tags inside parent divs to be contained and centered relative to container div rather then window size.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jTpGs/3/ ?

Comment: @Passerby no. I want p to be constrained inside the container div (which is 960px wide and centered)

Comment: @siner55 I'm not sure if I understand correctly. You want two `P`s to be centered _to the **red** container_ and yet maintaining their DOM position inside two `windowdiv`?

Comment: @Passerby yes exactly. p is just a simplistic example. there could be divs inside windowdiv.

Comment: @siner55 Do you have to put the `P`s under `windowdiv` in DOM, or they're OK to be placed directly under `container`? And is your `container` _always_ in 960px?

Comment: @Passerby P should be a child of windowdiv. and container will be 960px wide.

Comment: @siner55 How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/jTpGs/4/ ?

Comment: @Passerby this defeats the purpose. whole idea is to show windowdiv and windowdiv2 outside of container while keeps the child constrained.

Comment: @siner55 Sorry that I'm forced to use a small screen here so I was not quite "sync" with your idea. Then what you're trying to accomplish is almost impossible, because you want to CSS-position `P` according to `container`, but also requires `P` must be DOM-inside `windowdiv`, whose CSS-position to `container` is CSS-unknown. If you really need to do this, involving JS might make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add to this to your CSS to center your text in the middle of those boxes:

```
​#windowdiv p, #windowdiv2 p {
    ​text-align: center;
    ​height: 100%;
    ​line-height: 180px;   
}​
```

This is assuming that your boxes are fixed height, because we set the line-height.  (200px - 20px (padding-top) = 180px)

Comment: I want p elements constrained inside #container div

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean.  I see the text inside your #windowdiv and your #windowdiv2 divs.  Elaborate.

Comment: See the comments beneath my question